# jQuery .live() with a parent link

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have some markup that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="someButton">
   <span class="play">play</span>
</a>
```

When I click play, the markup changes to this:

```
<a href="#" class="someButton">
   <span class="stop">stop</span>
</a>
```

I am binding to the parent link, which is always there, just the class of the child element changes. How do I do this with .live()?

This is my current code

```
$('.play').parent('a').live('click', function() {
    console.log('PLAY');
});

// stop
$('.stop').parent('a').live('click', function() {
    console.log('stop');
});
```

I should also note that I dont have control over the markup changing as its a 3rd party video player but someone higher up in the organization.

Comment: You should consider revising and using jQuery.delegate() instead.  http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.someButton').live('click', function(){
    if ( $(this).find('.stop').length ) {
        console.log('stop');
    } else if ( $(this).find('.play').length ) {
        console.log('play');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry i want to bind to the parent link, not the span.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use ".live()" when your jQuery object was directly created by a selector.  You can't "navigate" to somewhere else via things like "find()".

With the ".delegate()" API, it's more explicit (and thus probably more clear):

```
$('whatever').delegate(selector, events, handler);
```

The "selector" argument can only be a string.  (Seems like it'd be nice if it could be a function.)

Comment: +1 The selector that `.live()` is ending up with looks like `".play.parent(a)"`. http://jsfiddle.net/dPLnC/

Comment: That's ... odd.  That doesn't really work (as a selector), does it? I guess you could add a pseudo-class extension, like a ":hasParent(selector)" trick or something.

Comment: As a selector, no it doesn't work at all. The only reason you get the selector is that `.live()` still returns a jQuery object, it just ignores the elements matched, and relies on the selector provided. jQuery must concatenate `".parent(a)"` for some special reason, but it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.play { color: green; }
.stop { color: red; }
```

Markup

```
<a href="#" class="someButton">
    <span class="play">Click</span>
</a>
```

Updated JS (thanks @patrick dw)

```
$('a:has(.play)').live('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('play').addClass('stop');
    alert('PLAY');
});

// stop
$('a:has(.stop)').live('click', function() {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('stop').addClass('play');
    alert('stop');
});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/2y7YJ/10/).

Comment: This makes the `.play` or the `.stop` element the target. OP wants the parent `<a>` to trigger the handler instead of just the child `<span>`.

Comment: CSS styling making the `a` element a larger area on the page than the inner `span`. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrAHK/) *(Using `.bind()` instead to simplify. The `.stop` element has a larger click area.)*

Comment: Well I thought the `live` requirement was more important. In my jsfiddle, we do not have a `.stop` initially, but the binding works because it is `live`. And `live` only works with selectors, not *elements*. So, as the selected answer suggests we should select the parent from the start and make the function figure out what should be done, or, select the span.

Comment: Yes, the  `.live()` requirement is important, and your solution makes the handler fire, just not on the element that OP desires. For a selector only solution, you'd need to do something like `$('a:has(.play)').live(...`, then traverse to the descendant if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know selectors could get that complex. But [they can](http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/2y7YJ/7/).

Comment: And, from a *what the OP asked for* perspective, *yours* is the correct answer.

Comment: Well, `:has()` is a proprietary selector. I tend to avoid those, but then I also avoid `.live()` in favor of `.delegate()`. :)